# WInJS: Full screen content for element or x-ms-webview

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, winjs, windows-8.1

I'm building an image viewer in a Windows 8 WinJS Application. When you click a thumb it loads a larger version of it in a placeholder on the page. It also has a video viewer in a x-ms-webview control.

Ideally what I would like to do is use something akin to the requestFullScreen() JS method to launch the larger version of the image in fullscreen mode. (I've tried requestFullScreen but it doesn't work).

I would also like to do a similar thing for the -x-ms-webview control where by the video inside can become full screen.

Are any of these things actually possible? Or should I resign myself to positioning them absolutely on the page?

Many thanks for your time.

Chris

Comment: You should be able t just use CSS to make the `x-ms-webview` element "fullscreen". Just give it 100% width and height% and position it `absolute` on the page (at `top:0; left: 0;`). You may have to tinker with `z-index` as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a class with JavaScript of fullscreen, set properties position: absolute, top: 0, left: 0, width: 100vw, height: 100vh.

That should make it full screen.